# Update PHP within XAMPP on MAC OSX

Tags: php, osx-snow-leopard, xampp

I've searched a few forums already and I haven't found a definitve answer. I'm aware that the XAMPP development for MAC OSX has been suspended, however I was hoping someone could outline the steps involved or point me to some other resources.

I'm currently using OSX 10.6.8, XAMPP 1.7.3, and PHP 5.3.1.

I guess this question should also expand to the updating of other components like phpmyadmin and mysql.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: My vote would be to bin XAMPP and install Apache/MySQL/PHP properly (separately). Then you won;t have this problem of relying on new releases of an all in one package to update individual components. It will also afford much more granular control over your environment, and help you learn how the individual components work under the bonnet.

Comment: +1 to Dave's recommendation. Also, if you don't want to go through the steps manually, I recommend [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/).

Comment: DaveRandom & Grexis - I was afraid you would suggest this path. I'm new to the CLI/Terminal and just don't feel like adding one more thing to the basket of "what I need to learn.". But I just may end up going this route, I need to learn it at some point. Thank you both for your input.

Comment: That's why I suggested Homebrew. It's commands are as simple as `brew install mysql`, or if you screw up, `brew remove mysql`

Comment: I do not understand why this question is closed for being "off topic".  This is a good question for professional programmers who got started with XAMPP and need to upgrade.  There is a similar, unanswered, question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178839/updating-mysql-in-xampp.   I like Dave's answer and will try it for myself.

Comment: I hope my comment is not considered to be critical.  I ask about the "closed as off topic" policy because I just want to understand.

Answer (score 2):

I use [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) and  Apache/MySQL/PHP which works perfect on my mac

Comment: I tried MAMP and found it a pain to get/enable https://. With XAMPP, I just modified one file and I was off and running. Thanks for your input though!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [one of these](http://alternativeto.net/software/xampp/?platform=mac) will be easier to figure out since they are built for mac? Otherwise, sorry can't help!