# Updating MySQL in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp, updates

XAMPP is currently delivered with MySQL 5.5.27.

How can I update this to a higher version?

(I need at least 5.6.4 because I need the fulltext-indices of innoDB)

I tried downloading the current version 5.6.10 for Windows and copy the files to the mysql-folder of XAMPP. But now it says that the server couldn't be started.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244420/update-php-within-xampp-on-mac-osx